# Where do this new line come from?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Reading "Learn Python the Hard Way", I am playing with Exercise 10

```
tabby_cat = "\tI'm tabbed in."
persian_cat = "I'm split\non a line."
backslash_cat = "I'm \\ a \\ cat."

fat_cat = """
I'll do a list:
\t* Cat food
\t* Fishies
\t* Catnip\n\t* Grass
"""

print tabby_cat
print persian_cat
print backslash_cat
print fat_cat
```

This produces the following output:

```
    I'm tabbed in.
I'm split
on a line.
I'm \ a \ cat.

I'll do a list:
    * Cat food
    * Fishies
    * Catnip
    * Grass
```

My question is: **Why there is a new line between the third and the fourth printed string? and how can I remove it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fat_cat = """ <-- here?
I'll do a list:
```

That is,

```
fat_cat = """I'll do a list:
...
```

removes it.

Comment: Dear herby, thank you. There is a way to print string on multiple lines without introducing new lines?

Comment: @Giuseppe: AFAIK not directly, you can use "first long part"+(new line)"second long line"+(new line) etc. or something like that.

Comment: Or you can strip the leading and trailing whitespace from strings first: `print(someString.strip())`; or if you just want to strip newlines `print(someString.strip('\n'))`.

Answer (score 5):

Because `print` always puts a newline (by default), the reason you've got another new line between the 3rd and fourth is that it contains an explicit `\n`

```
print fat_cat,
```

The above suppresses the implicit newline for the final output.

Comment: Not true, third string does not end with explicit `\n` (the fourth one does, but that was not part of the question).

Comment: @herby if we take logical lines, then the last contains an `\n`

Answer (score 2):

You can also escape the new line in the multi line string.

Compare these

```
fat_cat = """
I'll do a list:
\t* Cat food
\t* Fishies
\t* Catnip\n\t* Grass"""

print '=====',fat_cat

fat_cat = """\
I'll do a list:
\t* Cat food
\t* Fishies
\t* Catnip\n\t* Grass"""

print '=====',fat_cat
```

The `\` escapes the first newline.

You can also do this:

```
txt='''\
1\
2\
3\
4\
'''

print txt
```

Which will print `1234` since all the `\n` in the string `txt` have been escaped with `\`.

And finally, you might be interested in how you only print lines if they contain something other than white space. Here is a demo of that:

```
txt='''
1
\t
2
\n\n\n\n\n\n
3

4
'''

print '\n'.join(line for line in txt.splitlines() if line.strip())
```

Which prints:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks drweck, by the way, I was also searching for examples of escaping sequences in python, so I have learnt of "\".